# How to check visibility of snack bar and click on action in e2e test using protractor?

Tags: angular, angular-material, protractor, e2e-testing

I do e2e testing using a protractor but facing an issue with the snack bar.
This is a screenshot of the working app:-[Working demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN3IC.png)

The problem is that how to check visibility of snackbar that snackbar is occur on page and how to click undo action on that snackbar

This is the code for snackbar:-

```
openSnackBar(payload) {
    const snackBarRef = this.snackbar.open(payload.message, 'Undo', {
      duration: 5000
    });

    snackBarRef
      .onAction()
      .pipe(take(1))
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.store.dispatch(payload.undoAction);
      });
  }
```

The e2e test flow is like this:-

1. search for books
2. check the count
3. Click want to read
4. click on the reading list and check the count which will be one
5. Check if snack bar appeared
6. Click undo action on the snackbar
7. Check if the readlist item count is zero

The e2e test file :

```
  it('Then: I should undo added book to reading list', async () => {
    await browser.get('/');
    await browser.wait(
      ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement($('tmo-root'), 'okreads')
    );

    const form = await $('form');
    const input = await $('input[type="search"]');
    await input.sendKeys('javascript');
    await form.submit();
    const items = await $$('[data-testing="book-item"]');
    expect(items.length).toBeGreaterThan(1);

    const wantToReadButton = await $$('[data-testing="want-to-read-button"]').get(0)
    await wantToReadButton.click();

    
    const readingListToggle = await $('[data-testing="toggle-reading-list"]');
    await readingListToggle.click();
    const readingListItems = await $$('[data-testing="readinglist-item"]');
    expect(readingListItems.length).toBe(1);

   // const snackBar = await browser.driver.findElement(By.tagName('simple-snack-bar'))
   
    // await element(by.buttonText('close')).click()
    // browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf($('simple-snack-bar')),5000)
    // await element(by.buttonText('Undo')).click();
    // const undoButton = await element(by.buttonText('Undo'));
    // await undoButton.click();
    // await browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element(by.css('.mat-simple-snackbar-action')).getWebElement());

  });
```

I tried with different option for snackbar visibility and for click on to undo action , but got error that snackbar element  isn't present

so please anyone give help regarding that ?

Answer (score 1):

`browser.wait` returns promise and thus needs `await` too. So

```
await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf($('simple-snack-bar')), 5000, 'snack bar not present')
```

should do the work, if the locator is correct

Comment: Thanks, @Sergey Pleshakov but the main concern is how to find that snack bar locator because when clicking on the want to read button that time snack bar occur and as well as toggle list is there  (you can refer to screenshot for that), so with the above approach still get a timeout error [Failed: Wait timed out after 5213ms], Kindly suggest regarding that.

Comment: I'm confused. Your header states you need to check visibility (if visible or not). According to your description, you have a problem because you don't handle waiting properly. But now you're asking how to find a locator. Which one of the 3 this question is really about?